# How to draw table with multiple variables

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm a beginner when it concerns mathematica. I just learnt how to plot my function, but I'm not sure how to draw the table that i want. So my plotted function is

```
Ωa := (qa + Na - 1)!/(qa! (Na - 1)!)
Ωb := (qb + Nb - 1)!/(qb! (Nb - 1)!)
Ωtotal = Ωa*Ωb ;
Na = 100;
Nb = 200;
qtotal = 100;
qb = qtotal - qa;

K = Table[{N[qa], N[Ωtotal]}, {qa, 0, N[qtotal], 1}];

L = ListPlot[K, PlotRange -> All];
```

How do I go about drawing a table with qa and omega, but also some other value included in the calculations, such as qb and Na

I want my headers to look like

qa | omega_a | qb | omega_b | omega_total |

Comment: You might want to look into `TableForm` or `Grid`

Answer (score 2):

You should read the docs on [defining functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions.html) in Mathematica. From there it is pretty convenient to generate tables of the values you want using `Table`, and then you can display this data with the appropriate headings and orientation using `TableForm`:

```
Module[{Ωa, Ωb, Ωtotal, Na = 100, Nb = 200, qb, qtotal = 100, data},
 Ωa[qa_] := (qa + Na - 1)!/(qa! (Na - 1)!);
 Ωb[qb_] := (qb + Nb - 1)!/(qb! (Nb - 1)!);
 Ωtotal[qa_, qb_] := Ωa[qa]*Ωb[qb];
 qb[qa_] := qtotal - qa;
 Print@Plot[Ωtotal[qa, qb[qa]], {qa, 0, qtotal}, PlotRange -> All];
 data = Table[{qa, Ωa[qa], qb[qa], Ωb[qb[qa]], Ωtotal[qa, qb[qa]]}, {qa, 0, qtotal}];
 TableForm[data, TableHeadings->{None,{"qa","omega_a","qb","omega_b","omega_total"}}]]
```

[image]